# MC3008 vs. Justboom amp

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-zero-w, analog-to-digital, gpiozero

I just ordered the [Justboom AMP Zero pHAT](https://www.justboom.co/product/justboom-amp-zero-phat/). My project needs reading analog signals, too. So I also ordered a [MCP3008](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) in order to convert from analog to digital.

My question: is it possible to connect both devices to the GPIO interface at the same time?

I plan to connect the MCP3008 via SPI to my Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Answer (score 1):

The link gives no indication of the pins actively used by the HAT.

You will need to contact the vendor or otherwise find out if it uses one or more of the SPI peripherals.

In practice I think it unlikely to use SPI so you should be okay.  Even if it uses both SPI you could bit bang SPI on the spare GPIO.

Your biggest problem may be find a way to physically connect your ADC to the pins you need (given the HAT may not expose them).

This [link](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/amp_zero]) (provided by @steve-robillard) shows that you will be fine.  You can use the main SPI device and plug into the female headers on the HAT.

Comment: Given the info on (pinout.xyz)[https://pinout.xyz/pinout/amp_zero] it does not appear to use the SPI pins and looks like it has some type of pass-through header.